# What could be the reason for difference in clarity on two different displays with approximately same DPI?

Tags: display, resolution, scaling, dpi

I have two displays -

1. LG 22" monitor (22MP68VQ) which has a FullHD resolution (1920x1080) with DPI = 100. Contents are displayed without scaling.
2. Lenovo X1 carbon 6th gen laptop screen (14") with the FullHD resolution (1920x1080) with DPI = 157. However contents are displayed with 150% scaling. So essentially, the display layout after scaling becomes 1280x720 with DPI - 105.

As you can observe from the above data that the effective DPI are 100 and 105 respectively, which are almost same. However, the clarity of the icons on the laptop screen (2) way better than the monitor screen (1).
Some icon screenshot are as below-
On monitor screen (1)

[image]

On laptop screen (2)

[image]

Note: viewing distance is almost the same.

I am planning to buy new monitors and to make a better decision did a lot of study to understand `resolution`, `DPI` and `viewing distance`. Despite that I am not able to understand the reason for this difference in clarity given both of them have almost same DPI.

**Edit: Even the comfort of viewing differs. ie, keeping both the screen at the same viewing distance, it is more eye straining to see text contents on monitor screen (1)**

Comment: You are misinterpreting. It’s really simple: Content on your laptop screen uses more pixels to display the same thing. Of course it’s better.

Answer (score 2):

The "News and Interests" taskbar item [is always blurry at 100% scaling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-21h1#1629msgdesc), independently of the monitor that it's displayed on. This was fixed in a later Windows build 19043.1081 (KB5003690).

Comment: okay. Thanks for pointing that particular link. However, my question is quite generic. I just picked up that snippet of the screen since it was more evident. However, even other parts of the screen have difference in clarity in different monitors; which is resulting in eye strain. What difference between the two displays could be playing a factor?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reset the settings of the monitor, it helped for me.!
The quality was definately increase from what it was.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkYFC.jpg)